# I cloned Windows to a larger SSD and computer won't show additional storage, no unallocated partition

Tags: partitioning, ssd, windows-11, disk-cloning

I wanted to upgrade my laptop with a double sized SSD so I have cloned Windows from the old one to the new one. From about 223GB (officially I think 250) to 500GB.

I followed and online tutorial on youtube, but they failed to mention that it happens often that after cloning the new larger size SSD won't show all the available size but the old SSD's size.

My old SSD was MBR and my new one was GPT. It was recommended to convert to GPT.

I successfully booted Windows from the new SSD after swapping them, but it won't show the whole capacity of it.

Solutions I found recommend

- resizing the partition of Windows. > Doesn't change anything except creates extra unallocated partition.
- I do not have unallocated partition, all partitions are allocated > the rest of the storage simply doesn't show.
  [image: partitions of SSD with no unallocated partition]

Hopefully the image will show, that I have no unallocated partition and disk management sees the capacity, but In Windows it doesn't show.
[image: windows showing old SSD storage size]

Please help me, I have never done this before and I have spent so much time trying to find a solution, and none of them would be applicable to my case.
Let me know if you need any further details.

Answer (score 5):

> I do not have unallocated partition, all partitions are allocated > the rest of the storage simply doesn't show

They are allocated, but not part of the main partition (the C: partition) and do not seem to have a valid file system/type:
[image]

What you should do is:

1. Delete all 3 of those incorrectly formatted partitions (so they become one big unallocated pool)
2. Use **Extend Volume** on the ***C:*** partition and include all the unallocated space